# Pentaho Report Designer 5.0.1 - Hide field with Empty field

Tags: reporting, pentaho

I am using Pentaho report designer 5.0 CE.

My report is having two groups, and one group contains row band with elements and values like,

`Group1
  Group2
  Label1 - Value1
  Label2 - Value2
  Label3 - Value3
 ...`

I need to show a row only if the value is not empty(without leaving blank space).
I set the 'invisible-consumes-space' property to false (band level). The blank space is still there.

how could i hide a label & value (entire row) if the value is empty?

Comment: found this ticket, while googling for my issue.
saying that 'invisible-consumes-space' not working in PRD CE 5.0
http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-4760

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to put the label element and value element in a band. assumingly value is printed by name field.

this is your band.

```
-----------------
|label  | name  |
-----------------
```

select the band from structure tree and go to **style tab->size&position -> visible** option.
then open the expression tab and paste

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Name]);"False"; "True")
```

OR

```
=IF(LEN([Name])<=0;"False"; "True")
```

I use the one below to hide all the group headers & footers when there is no data.

1. set no data band -> hide-on-canvas option to false. Add a message
   field and let's say 'No data available for selected date range'
2. And set all Report Header & Footer's visible option to:

> =IF(ISEMPTYDATA();"False"; "True")

And it works.
Hope helps to you too.

Comment: Hi Ozland,
I have used
 
    =IF(ISBLANK([Name]);"False"; "True")

it worked for me, i might try ISBLANK also(Hope it will work).

Comment: Redundant `IF`. You could simply write `=LEN([name]) > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

And empty string is not the same as an invisible element. Use the "visible" style instead and add your formula to the band's "visible" style setting to hide the band and all its subbands.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I tried the same logic u told. the problem is the band became invisible if the particular column value is empty. but still empty space occurs. I changed the band's y position to '0'(though i don't prefer this) as a workaround.

Comment: As I said in the other post of yours: Use separate bands for each record type and make the parent band of these per-record band a "block" layout band. If the layout is undefined, then the reporting engine will use "canvas" as layout, which does not reposition the other bands once a record-band becomes invisible.